# Is DataContract attributes required for WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, serialization

I'm writing WCF service and his client. I want to send/receive objects of my custom classes, between service and client.

I have 3 modules

- WCF service
- WCF client
- common class library

Both WCF service and client have references to common class library.
I don't want to mark all my class with DataContract attributes.

So, my question "Is DataContract attributes required for WCF?"

I use .NET 4 and netTcpBinding.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If I recall correctly(IIRC), if you don't use formal data-contract markers, it defaults to acting like a field-serializer. This will work, but is less easy to version, since private changes can break the client/server. IMO you should always formally decorate WCF types with the data-contract/data-member attributes. It will work without them, but for the wrong reasons (IIRC, originally it *didn't* work without formal markers).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127%28v=vs.110%29.aspx says only public read/write properties and fields are included in the contract by default.

Answer (score 7):

> "Is DataContract attributes required
>   for WCF"

Technically, no. This is dependent on whether you use the DataContractSerializer or not (which is the default on many bindings).

There are other options:

1. Consider alternative serializers
2. Try using [Data Contract Surrogates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733064.aspx) (attributes are still required *somewhere*, but it does potentially mean u can leave your class untouched, if thats relevant)
3. Rely on the [serialization defaults](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656732.aspx) for when you serialize classes without Data Contract attributes

Comment: Retracted ContractDescription advice. I suspect you could use the ContractDescription to change the serializer somehow

Answer (score 3):

You can use several serializaton techniques with WCF, it's one of the nice adaptable things about it. Have a look:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163569.aspx

Answer (score 3):

It's not required to use DataContract attributes, your service will work just fine without them.

Having said that, I really don't think having your service and client share a class library is the best design approach. It would be a lot clearer if you'd expose your types through DataContracts.

What would happen when someday, someone wants to consume your service but don't have access to the shared class library?

Comment: When service has a method([OperationContract]), which has argument of my custom class and that class does not have default constructor, I receive InvalidDataContractException from WCF service host.

Comment: Even if both your service and client share a class library, WCF is going to try to serialize your types and for that it needs a default constructor. Your design violates the very principles of web service design and I would argue you'd be better off using something else like .NET remoting.