# Passing objects vs records in F# web service

Tags: wcf, f#

As I know I can passing the objects and the records in WCF F# Web Service:

```
[<DataContract>]
type Item(id : string, name : string) = 
    [<DataMember>]
    member val ItemId = id with get, set
    [<DataMember>]
    member val ItemName = name with get, set

    new() = new Item("", "")

type Person = 
    {
        First : string
        Last : string
        Age : int
    }
```

Web Service Implementation:

```
type SimpleService() =
    interface ISimpleService with
        member x.GetItems() =
            let sql = new SqlConnector()
            let result = sql.GetItems()
            result
        member x.GetPerson() =
            let result = { First = "Steve"; Last = "Holt"; Age = 17 }
            result
        member x.GetPeople() =
            let a = { First = "Steve"; Last = "Holt"; Age = 17 }
            let b = { First = "Dan"; Last = "Woller"; Age = 34 }
            [| a; b |]
```

I am just wondering which way is better - to pass objects and to pass records in F# service?

As I see it is possible to get record as object on the client side if it was written in C#.

As I see I don't need to annotate my record type to pass it as result or parameter of Web Service.

Am I right?

Comment: Record is compiled to serializable sealed .NET class with public readonly properties. So which way is better depends on how you want to use this class. For records you can use attribute `[<CLIMutable>]` then compiled class object could be modified in C# code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes [aren't *required* for WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5921635/126014) - only *recommended* (strongly).

An F# record compiles to an immutable class in IL, so WCF will see it as an unannotated immutable class. As Petr writes in a comment to the question itself, you can put `[<CLIMutable>]` on your record, like this:

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type Person = 
{
    First : string
    Last : string
    Age : int
}
```

This will make it look like a mutable class (with parameterless constructor and writable properties) to other code than F#. You don't need this in WCF as long as you only **send** data (as in your question above), but if you ever want to **receive** data (which arrives as XML infosets), WCF must be able to deserialize the XML infoset into your record, and it can only do that if the class is mutable.

You can also put attributes on your record, like this:

```
[<DataContract; CLIMutable>]
type Person = 
{
    [<DataMember>]
    First : string
    [<DataMember>]
    Last : string
    [<DataMember>]
    Age : int
}
```

Between the service and the clients, there are no .NET types - only XML (infosets). Client code is generated from WSDL (XML schema documents), so a C# client will generate the types in the web service as C# classes.