# Confused about protobuf-net WCF usage

Tags: c#, wcf, protobuf-net

I have been following [this tutorial](http://blog.marcgravell.com/2009/11/controlling-wcf-protobuf-net-at.html) to add `protobuf-net` to my WCF project. I have a shared DTO library. Both server and Client use those DTO classes. I have attributed all my Service methods with `[OperationContract]` attributes, but i have not assigned any `[DataContract]` attributes on my DTO classes.

I added the `protobuf-net` Nuget package and added the configuration to the `web.config`.

I am using IIS Express to test my service, and thought that i should be ok with what i had done so far. However, after testing a few calls, i noticed that i forgot to add `protobuf-net` to my client and yet everything worked as expected (ie. no errors from serialization or deserialization).

I suspect that protobuf is not used in my program at all, and that i am missing something. [I'd like to avoid using `[DataContract]` attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921635/is-datacontract-attributes-required-for-wcf) but i could live with adding them, if that is what is need to get `protobuf-net` working.

What else am i missing?

Comment: content negotiation & fallback to a different serialization format?

Comment: Just a comment: as of .NET 3.5 SP1, you do not need to use data contract attributes, all public members are serialized by default. If, however, you apply one attribute, then you need to apply them everywhere.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? If so, could you add it here as an answer? I am looking for information on this.

Answer (score 1):

A year ago I faced the same problem, where protoBuf seems to be an excellent option, with WCF it has some shortcomings.

I created an open source project to overcome these shortcomings, it uses protobu-net library and adds functionality to it, such that you don't need to share assemblies anymore with client. It however again requires you to put DataContract attributes though currently.

You can give it a try: https://github.com/maingi4/ProtoBuf.Wcf

DISCLAIMER: I am creator and owner of the above project.