# WCF return custom objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

How can I return list of custom objects (stored in class library outside wcf project) from WCF without adding same objects in WCF project with `[DataContract]` flags?

I have added reference of my class library to wcf project and put tick on reusing assemblies in WCF references. WCF doesnt return my objects ( but it does reach them, because it returns string properties of these objects without any problems )

Comment: What do you mean by _"WCF doesnt return my objects"_?

Comment: When I try to return `List<MyObject> I'm getting an error. However, I can return `String item = List<MyObject>[1].Name;`

Comment: Then research that error. If you did, show it in your question and share your research. Read [ask].

Comment: This is your question answered (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921635/is-datacontract-attributes-required-for-wcf)